# Looped invoke in scxml event

Tags: recursion, scxml, apache-commons-scxml

I have an scxml event with an "invoke" element. This invoke element updates the datamodel elements when the event is called. How can I make this happen periodically? Is it possible to periodically call this invoke for example, every second? Or perhaps to transition to the event every second?

The problem with the latter is that if I put a transition in the finalize section of the invoke, calling itself, it does not seem to call the invoke section more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first wanted to provide some background on `<invoke>`. `<invoke>` is placed as a child to `<state>`. It starts a child state machine session on entering the state, and stops the session on exiting the state. Furthermore, if the child session enters a `<final>` state, then a `done.invoke.invokeid` event is dispatched on the parent session. You can use this `done.invoke.invokeid` event in a transition on the parent state, to force the parent state to exit when the child session terminates. Finally, the parent and child states can communicate with each other through `<send>`. The parent can communicate with the child using `<send>` with `target` attribute set to `_invoke_invokeid`, and the child can communicate with the parent through `<send>` with `target` attribute set to `_parent`.

Now, onto your questions:

> This invoke element updates the datamodel elements when the event is called.

I think there may be a problem with the way you have conceptualized this, because the invoked session has its own datamodel (which is to say, its own memory). You can bind the initial datamodel values of the child session using `<param>`, but you can't really share memory between the parent and child sessions. This means that you can't update the datamodel in the parent session directly in the child session using e.g. `<assign>` or `<script>` tags.

The only way for the child session to update the datamodel in the parent session is to communicate with the parent session through passing events (e.g. `<send event="update" target="_parent"><param name="dataToUpdate" expr="dataToUpdate"/></send>`). The parent then needs to have a `<transition>` element so that it can process the event sent from the child session, e.g. `<transition event="update"><assign location="dataToUpdate" expr="_event.dataToUpdate"/></transition>`.

This leads to the question of whether `<invoke>` is the best, simplest approach to updating the datamodel periodically. It might be simpler to, for example, just put the datamodel update logic inside of a child of `<parallel>` state. This way, you could use `<assign>` to update the datamodel directly.

> How can I make this happen periodically? Is it possible to periodically call this invoke for example, every second? Or perhaps to transition to the event every second?

To invoke a session periodically, you would enter and exit the state containing the `<invoke`> element. The following (untested) code would probably work:

```
<state id=invokeParent">
  <!-- this is some data that you want the child session to update in the parent session -->
  <datamodel>
    <data id="dataToUpdate" />
  </datamodel>
  <onentry>
    <send event="loop" delay="1s"/> <!-- send the 'loop' event every second to loop in invokeParent -->
  </onentry>
  <transition event="loop" target="invokeParent" /> <!-- this transition will exit and re-enter the state, restarting the invoked session -->
  <transition event="done.invoke.myInvoke" target="invokeParent" /> <!-- also loop if the invoked session terminates -->
  <invoke id="myInvoke" type="scxml" src="file:test276sub1.scxml"/> <!-- this is the invoke -->
  <!-- this targetless transition handles the update event sent from the child session to the parent to update the parent's datamodel -->
  <transition event="update">
    <assign location="dataToUpdate" expr="_event.dataToUpdate"/>
  </transition>
</state>
```

> The problem with the latter is that if I put a transition in the finalize section of the invoke, calling itself, it does not seem to call the invoke section more than once.

I don't believe `transition` is a legal child of `finalize`. `finalize` is meant to contain executable content (e.g. `script`, `assign`) that allow you to manipulate events sent by the child session before they are processed by the parent session.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#finalize

Comment: Wow this is a detailed reply. Thank you, it really clarifies things for me. I was mistaken by saying I put a transition in finalize. What I actually did was raise an event that triggered a transition in my finalize. Thanks very much

Comment: In the above code, what raises the "update" event? PS. I believe that I had tried a solution similar to the above, but for some reason the invoke is only being entered on the first "iteration"...

Comment: Re:  what raises the "update" event. In the invoked session, you would send the event to the parent session like this: `<send event="update" target="_parent"><param name="dataToUpdate" expr="dataToUpdate"/></send>`

Comment: Re: I believe that I had tried a solution similar to the above, but for some reason the invoke is  only being entered on the first "iteration". Apache commons was written before the SCXML specification was finalized and I believe is not fully compliant. It may have some bugs compared to the spec. You might want to look at some other implementations which better comply with the spec, such as uscxml https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml or my library SCION http://scion.scxml.io/ which are both fully compliant

Comment: @jbeard4 hi there. could we email you about a small consulting project (really, just an architecture question on SVG)? will delete this comment once you read it. thanks!

Comment: hi @Crashalot I just saw your comment now, ~2 years later. Sorry about that.

Comment: @jbeard4 I need help as it is hard to find SCXML expert here on stackoverflow or reading papers about it.  Is there way I can communicate with you in detaield way I mean via email something ? Also do you suggest some good books on SCXML or resources? Thanks :)

Comment: @Joker Feel free to reach me on the SCION-SCXML chat room here: https://gitter.im/SCION-SCXML/Lobby

Comment: @Joker or you can post your questions to stackoverflow with the scxml tag